# Couldn't initialize a HttpClusterStateProvider (is/are the Solr server(s), [localhost:8983], down?)

Tags: solr

I am new to Solr 7.3.0 on MacOS.

I am trying to build a Solr Cloud Server.

```
object CloudSolRServerBuilder {
  def build(zkHost: String): CloudSolrClient = {
    new CloudSolrClient.Builder(mutable.Buffer(zkHost)).build()
  }
```

I get the following error info

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't initialize a HttpClusterStateProvider (is/are the Solr server(s), [localhost:8983], down?)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient$Builder.build(CloudSolrClient.java:1550)
    at org.PT.SparkDataPipeline.CloudSolRServerBuilder$.build(SolRSupport.scala:15)
    at org.PT.SparkDataPipeline.RunDataPipeline$.main(RunDataPipeline.scala:42)
    at org.PT.SparkDataPipeline.RunDataPipeline.main(RunDataPipeline.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occured when talking to server at: localhost:8983
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:657)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:255)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:244)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.request(SolrClient.java:1219)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClusterStateProvider.fetchLiveNodes(HttpClusterStateProvider.java:191)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClusterStateProvider.<init>(HttpClusterStateProvider.java:65)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient$Builder.build(CloudSolrClient.java:1548)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException: URI does not specify a valid host name: localhost:8983/admin/collections?action=CLUSTERSTATUS&wt=javabin&version=2
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.determineTarget(CloseableHttpClient.java:95)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:542)
    ... 9 more
```

I checked localhost:8983 and I can access Solr Admin UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [docs](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/7_3_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/CloudSolrClient.Builder.html) you will see the string you are passing to the CloudSolrClient is not the right one, it should be something like:

```
String zkHostString = "zkServerA:2181";
```

(actually, a list like of such strings, if you have a zk ensemble).